# Powershell - Find computers with a specific username logged in

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I've been trying to figure out a powershell script that doing a search of all computers
with a specific username logged in.

so far I've found a way looking via all computers the 'explorer.exe' process and owner

Also I found this script:

```
Function Get-Username {
    Clear-Host
    $Global:Username = Read-Host "Enter Username"
    if ($Username -eq $null){
        Write-Host "Username cannot be blank, please enter a Username"
        Get-Username
    }
    $UserCheck = Get-ADUser $Username
    if ($UserCheck -eq $null){
        Write-Host "Invalid Username, please verify this is the logon id for the account"
        Get-Username
    }
}
Get-Username

Function Get-Computername {
    Clear-Host
    $Global:Prefix = Read-Host "Enter Computername"
    Clear-Host
}
Get-Computername

$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Enabled -eq 'true' -and SamAccountName -like $Prefix}
$CompCount = $Computers.Count
Write-Host "Searching for $Username on $Prefix on $CompCount Computers`n"

foreach ($comp in $computers){
    $Computer = $comp.Name
    $Reply = $null
    $Reply = test-connection $Computer -count 1 -quiet
    if($Reply -eq 'True'){
        if($Computer -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME){
            $proc = gwmi win32_process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -computer $Computer -Filter "Name = 'explorer.exe'"
        }
        else{
            $proc = gwmi win32_process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Credential $Credential -computer $Computer -Filter "Name = 'explorer.exe'"
        }           

            $progress++         
            ForEach ($p in $proc) {             
                $temp = ($p.GetOwner()).User
                Write-Progress -activity "Working..." -status "Status: $progress of $CompCount Computers checked" -PercentComplete (($progress/$Computers.Count)*100)
                if ($temp -eq $Username){
                write-host "$Username is logged on $Computer"
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

This is not my script, only trying to use it.

this script can take a very long long time, trying to run on about 300 machines, it can take for 20 minutes run.

now im not sure, which part is taking most of the time, im thinking either the gwmi win32 process, that checking on each machine if the process 'explorer.exe' is on
or the part test-connection that trying to ping each machine first, and then check for the 'explorer.exe' process.

for your knowledge, is there any faster way with powershell script to do this kind of checkup?
to search for a specific username on which machines logged on?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You want to see who the current logged in user is on each machine, or all the users who have logged into the system? `gwmi` is slow, and you should also be using the newer *CIM* cmdlets,  but so is testing for each computer to see if it's online. `Get-CimInstance` accepts an array of computers that will be ran on parallel when queried. Since you're not doing anything with the machines that aren't online, you can silence the output. `Write-Progress` is also terribly slow.

Comment: Hi @AbrahamZinala Thanks for the respond! Yes, im trying to see who the current logged in user in on each machine. ok i will read about this CIM, see if that can work better. and i will defiantly silence the Write-Progress if that also makes the process much slower. but, is this scrip basically good enough to keep testing and playing with it?

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/query-user.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment. . .

Here's an quick and dirty approach you can take:

```
Function Get-Username {
    Clear-Host
    $Global:Username = Read-Host "Enter Username"
    if ($Username -eq $null){
        Write-Host "Username cannot be blank, please enter a Username"
        Get-Username
    }
    $UserCheck = Get-ADUser $Username
    if ($UserCheck -eq $null){
        Write-Host "Invalid Username, please verify this is the logon id for the account"
        Get-Username
    }
}
Get-Username
Function Get-Computername {
    Clear-Host
    $Global:Prefix = Read-Host "Enter Computername"
    Clear-Host
}
Get-Computername

$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Enabled -eq $true -and SamAccountName -like $Prefix}

$check = Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT Name,UserName from Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE UserName LIKE '%$userName%'" `
                -ComputerName $Computers.Name`
                -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($check) { 
    # $check.UserName/Name may return an array same name users are found. 
    Write-Output -InputObject ($check.UserName + " is logged into: " + $check.Name)
}
else {
    Write-Output -InputObject "Unable to find $userName."
}
```

Seeing as you're not doing nothing with the systems that you're unable to ping, you can silence the output and only returning the results for the ones that are online. Best solution for you scenario and question, is to take advantage of the *parallelization* that `Get-CIMInstance` allows you to do when passing an array of computers to `-ComputerName`.

- `Write-Progress` tends to be terribly slow and if you're looking for a fast solution, this will definitely slow you down.
- `Get-WMIObject` is a deprecated cmdlet that has been superseded by `Get-CIMInstance` which offers the same functionality, with a safer remoting procedure.
- Using `-Query`, we can use [WQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wql-sql-for-wmi) to search at the time of query speeding up the process some more. The only downside to some admins is that it follows its own syntax.

---

*One thing to note, if you can ping a machine, it doesn't mean you can connect to it.*

Comment: with this script its unable to find any username i input. trying to figure out now

Comment: Can you try it against your username? Edit: I see now. Your `Get-UserName` function returns an *ADObject* instead of the a simple string. Reference the property you want to query by on `$username`. Probably going to be your samaccountname property.

Comment: also, just tested few other while playing with the -Query instead of ComputerSystem, tried the old Process for explorer.exe, that looks like did some trick, and does finding the Users, but nvm which user i input, all same results. either its 'admin', 'administrator' or any existing user i have in my AD... so still something is wrong here either with Win32_ComputerSystem and Win32_Process

Comment: See the edit on my comment

Comment: so what should i change in the query? i tried select *, and select  SamAccountName, and WHERE name, or WHERE  SamAccountName , and also like 'SamAccountName' etc etc... Edit: oh yeah also tried without query, straight Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem with object property etc...

Comment: Recopy the code and see if it works for you. Just edited my answer

Comment: still the same, i already added my self the line for $computers before...

Comment: And you can confirm there is a value in both variables of `$username` and `$computers`?

Comment: yes both value inputs for $username and for $computers are correct and exists. my guess is something to do with the query. but cant figure what

Comment: What PowerShell version are you running? Have you tried running through the code one line at a time? So you can highlight `$username`, click F8 (on your keyboard), and it returns a value? `$computers` will return an array.

Comment: Are you adding an asterisk after the prefix?

Comment: yes every computer name im ending with asterisk

Comment: not sure broski, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

this is a slightly different approach. [*grin*] it presumes that you may want to check on more than one user name, so it grabs ALL the users on ALL the systems. once you have that, you can query for the one you want ... and then query for the next without having to wait for the system list to be scanned again.

the code ...

```
$ComputerList = @"
LocalHost
10.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
BetterNotBeThere
$env:COMPUTERNAME
"@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a list of computer names


$GCIMI_Params = @{
    ClassName = 'CIM_ComputerSystem'
    ComputerName = $ComputerList
    ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
    # this will hold the errors from the non-repsonding systems - if you want that info
    ErrorVariable =  'NonResponderList'
    }
$LoggedInUserList = Get-CimInstance @GCIMI_Params |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            # the ".Split()" gets rid of the domain/workgroup/system part of the UserName
            UserName = $_.UserName.Split('\')[-1]
            ComputerName = $_.DNSHostName
            # this shows the name used by the G-CimI call - it can be different
            QueryComputerName = $_.PSComputerName
            }
        }

#get your target user name
$TargetUserName = $env:USERNAME

#get the system that name is logged into
$LoggedInUserList.Where({$_.UserName -eq $TargetUserName})
```

output on my system today ...

```
UserName    ComputerName QueryComputerName
--------    ------------ -----------------
MyUserName  MySysName    MySysName            
MyUserName  MySysName    LocalHost        
MyUserName  MySysName    127.0.0.1
```

what the code does ...

- builds a list of systems to check
  when you are ready to do this with real data, just remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block & replace it with your `Get-ADComputer` call.
- builds a `splat` of the parameters for the `Get-CimInstance` call
- sends the `G-CimI` call to the target systems
- generates a `[PSCustomObject]` containing the desired properties
- sends that PSCO out to a results collection
- grabs a user name
- filters the results collection
- shows the system[s] the user name is logged into - if there are any

note that i only have one system, so the 3 responses are all from that same box. also note that the computer can be referred to by DNS name, IP address, or `LocalHost`.

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for your answer! but actually i'm looking more like the script i've posted, the request i've had is to input a username, and search where it logged in. and the search could be for hundreds or thousands machines, for example like in the script, i need to input user name lets say 'admin' (for example) and search where this 'admin' currently logged right now. the script i've posted does that, but it takes very very long time. also i think something is wrong with it, now that im trying to run it, every user i input, gives the same results...

Comment: @VladBelo - have you tested the timing of my code in your situation? it should take no longer ... and may take less time since it runs the code in parallel on the target systems.

Comment: No i have not tested your code, i do not understand part of it, and when im trying to run it on Powershell its all messed up

Comment: @VladBelo - so ... have you tried running JUST the code i posted ... as is? that is how to test the basic logic ... and if you have glitches, ask about them and post the error text. [*grin*]

Comment: yes yes i've tried running just the code you posted. there are missing terminator strings, and while trying to figure out, it gets more complicated.

Comment: @VladBelo - AHA! [*grin*] i finally noticed that i left off the 1st 3 lines of code. please try it again ... and next time, PLEASE let folks know the EXACT errors you get so they can fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to read the remote registry on these computers?

If so:

1. **Get a list for registry keys from** \\{Computername}\HKU
2. **Filter out all that DO NOT end with '_Classes'**

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-4155237567-380904213-1424831347-1001
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-4155237567-380904213-1424831347-1005
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-4155237567-380904213-1424831347-1005_Classes
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-4155237567-380904213-1424831347-500
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-515967899-1938372697-839532595-26824
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-515967899-1938372697-839532595-3976
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-515967899-1938372697-839532595-3976_Classes
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18
```

*becomes*

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-4155237567-380904213-1424831347-1005_Classes
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-515967899-1938372697-839532595-3976_Classes
```

3. **From the now filtered list remove '_Classes' from the end of the keys.**

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-4155237567-380904213-1424831347-1005_Classes
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-515967899-1938372697-839532595-3976_Classes
```

*becomes*

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-4155237567-380904213-1424831347-1005
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-515967899-1938372697-839532595-3976
```

4. **If any remain, then try to read the "USERNAME" value from the "Volatile Environment" key from each.**

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-4155237567-380904213-1424831347-1005\Volatile Environment
{Throws error, was just a ghost of past login - not real}
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-515967899-1938372697-839532595-3976\Volatile Environment
    USERNAME    REG_SZ    {UserName}
```

5. **Been doing this from BATCH language with REG.EXE and don't believe I've ever seen 2 names come back from step 4 above.  If no keys remains after step 3, or all attempts to read USERNAME fails in step 4, then no one is logged on.  If one name comes back, I guess it could be a ghost left over from a system crash, but in theory, it should be the user logged on.**

I've seen PSLoggedOn \{ComputerName} fail to give correct info, so I think this is simply a very hard thing to do since Windows will crash, or have other problems, and leaves ghost fragments from past users.

Sorry I don't PowerShell code, still fairly new to PowerShell and haven't nose dived into the registry that far yet.

If I really needed to know for a fact who is logged on or not, I would investigate seeing if there is a way to get a script to run every 2 minutes while the user is logged in, and have the script save a UserName/DateTime stamp at the end of a log file in \Users\Public every time it ran.  But I would have to want it bad to do that much work.

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure if getting list of registry will be faster then the script im using. anyway tnx, but i'm trying to stick with the powershell script i posted, just trying to figure out a way to make the search much faster

Answer (score 0):

Here's is an alternative method that does not iterarte all computers in the domain, **but** it relies on all users have their Home directories redirected to a network share.

If that is the case in your domain, try:

```
# enter the SamAccountName of the user you are looking for
$user = 'SamAccountName'

# the UNC (\\Server\Share) name of the network share where all user homedirectories are
$usersHomePath = '\\HomesServer\HomesShare$' 

# split the UNC path to get the server name and share name in separate variables
$server, $share = $usersHomePath.TrimStart("\") -split '\\'



$result = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ServerConnection -ComputerName $server | 
            Where-Object { $_.ShareName -eq $share -and $user -eq $_.UserName } |
            Select-Object @{Name = "SamAccountName"; Expression = { $_.UserName }}, 
                          @{Name = "ComputerName"; Expression = {(([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($_.ComputerName).HostName) -split "\.")[0]}}

#output in console
$result
```

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, I don't think you will ever get super fast access of who is logged on.  The only real approach is to multi-thread it with something like Split-Pipeline.
https://github.com/nightroman/SplitPipeline

Once you install SplitPipeline, your code will need a framework like this:

```
function MakePackage {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$UserName,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$ComputerName
    )
    process {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName    = $ComputerName
            UserName        = $UserName
        }
    }
}

$UserName = Read-Host "Please enter the username to search for"
$ComputerNames = @( 'ComputerName1', 'ComputerName2', 'ComputerName3', 'ComputerName4')
$ComputerNames | MakePackage $UserName | Split-Pipeline -Count 10 {
    begin {
        # Your functions go here.
    }
    Process {
        [string]$ComputerName   = $_.ComputerName
        [string]$UserName       = $_.UserName
        # Your main code goes here.
        Write-Host "Looking for $UserName on computer $ComputerName"        
    }
}
```

Comment: Re-wrote the code to package the computer name and username together to make them accessible inside the Process section.